# How do I make this JOIN?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im doing a college project with entity framework and i'm doing some JOIN's. I was doing well until I got to this JOIN that I don't know how to do.
Simplifying the functionality I have to implement: I have a button and when I click on it, it must show all the information from the tables, that's why I need to make the JOIN's, and I created a model for this purpose.

This is a screenshot of my SQL database:
[SQL Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Lvc.png)

And this is the code where I need to make the MetaEspecifica JOIN where the 
foreign key is from AreaProcesso :

```
// GET: AreaProcesso/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var item = (from ap in db.AreaProcesso
                    join mg in db.MetaGenerica on ap.IdAreaProcesso equals mg.IdMetaGenerica
                    join model in db.Modelo on ap.IdAreaProcesso equals model.IdModelo
                    from nc in db.NivelCapacidade
                    from c in db.Categoria
                    from me in db.MetaEspecifica
                    where ap.IdAreaProcesso == id.Value
                    select new AreaProcessoModelView()
                    {
                        SiglaMetaGenerica = mg.Sigla,
                        NomeMetaGenerica = mg.Nome,
                        DescricaoMetaGenerica = mg.Descricao,
                        Sigla = ap.Sigla,
                        Nome = ap.Nome,
                        Descricao = ap.Descricao,
                        SiglaModelo = model.Sigla,
                        NomeModelo = model.Nome,
                        DescricaoModelo = model.Descricao,
                        SiglaNivelCapacidade = nc.Sigla,
                        NomeNivelCapacidade = nc.Nome,
                        DescricaoNivelCapacidade = nc.Descricao,
                        NomeCategoria = c.Nome
                    }).FirstOrDefault();

        if (item == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();  // Or a return a view with message "item not found"
        }
        return View(item);
    }
```

Comment: You should probably be using the navigation properties, not doing manual joins.

Comment: So whats the issue? What do you need help with?

Comment: I tried do this: "join ap in db.AreaProcesso on me.IdAreaProcesso equals ap.IdAreaProcesso" but the ap variable it's already declared!

Comment: look up how to use Navigation Properties @AugustoKernath

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx go through this link

Comment: Thanks @RudreshaParameshappa, I'll look it!

Comment: "NivelCapacidade,Categoria,MetaEspecifica", those tables are  not join with other table  values should be null

Answer (score 0):

If you need have HTML page with JSON use this section under view page

```
@section Scripts {
    var jsonData= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.YourDataCollection));
}
```

If you only need JSON data in the browser, change your controller and return Json like this:

```
return Json(item, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Be careful if use return Json you say MVC this is not view page and only data serialization page**

To view Details.cshtml file does not need a model, only after the design page layout only add this script in the script section

```
@section Scripts {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '@Url.Action("Details")',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            // use json result
        }
    });
}
```